# Time stamp being displayed differently

Tags: java, angular, oracle, java-8, angular8

I am fetching records from database(oracle 12c) and displaying them in front end . When they are in database the the timestamp format is

```
23-07-20 08:18:19.702000000 PM
```

I am not converting to any format in front end . I am simply displaying it as string . Strangely the format in the front end  is appearing like this

```
2020-7-23 20:7:0. 378000000
```

I need to take timestamp which is in front end as input and insert it in database in a new row . While I am inserting , I am getting **ORA-01843: not a valid month** error .How can I resolve this

The below is how I am fetching record from db:

```
try {
            sftpList=jt.query(env.getProperty("FETCH_SFTP_QUERY"),rs ->{
                List<SftpDashBoardTableBean> sftp_List = new ArrayList<>();
                SftpDashBoardTableBean sftpDashBoardTableBean=null;
                while(rs.next()) {
                    
                sftpDashBoardTableBean.setCreatedDate(rs.getString("CREATED_DATE"));
                
                sftp_List.add(sftpDashBoardTableBean);
                
                }
//Exception Handling
```

Below is my model class in front end(angular)

```
export class EditSftpModel {
    

    createdBy:string;
     createdDate:string;//this is displayed as timestamp in front end
    recVersion:string;
    editedBy:string;
    editedDate:string;
    availType:string;
    isActive:string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using datePipe to format your date values?

```
private datePipe: DatePipe // in constructor

// in setCreateDate
this.datePipe.transform( rs.getString("CREATED_DATE"), 'long' );
```

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe